# Call WebAPI from HTML5 page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to bind json response from WebAPI call in a HTML5 page.  Not sure where I am off.  The WebAPI returns this json:

```html
{
  "ID": 1,
  "Date": "2015-10-26T00:00:00",
  "Status": "Initiated",
  "Action": {
    "VerificationActionTypeID": 0,
    "VerificationActionType": null,
    "VerificationActionTakenID": 0,
    "VerificationActionTaken": null,
    "VerficationActionCreateDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "EmailAddress": null,
    "Notes": null
  },
  "Actions": [
    {
      "VerificationActionTypeID": 0,
      "VerificationActionType": "Perform Rinse Flowcell",
      "VerificationActionTakenID": 0,
      "VerificationActionTaken": "Skip",
      "VerficationActionCreateDate": "2015-10-26T10:04:05.093",
      "EmailAddress": null,
      "Notes": null
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my jQuery code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uri = 'http://localhost/Custom.WebAPI/api/action?verificationid=1';
    var $result = $('#Result');
    var msg;
    $(document).ready(function () {             
        $.getJSON(uri)
            .done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    alert("action: " + item);
                    $('#actions tbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.ID + '</td><td>' + item.Status + '</td></tr>');
                });
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {                    
                var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                msg = "Failed to get action data Error message is " + error.message;                    
                alert("Message: " + msg);
            });
    });        
</script>
```

My HTML:

```html
<body>
    <aside id="data">
        <div id="Result"> </div>
        <table id="actions">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </aside>
</body>
```

This is what shows on the html page:

[image: html5 page]

Notice this line I have in the javascript:
alert("action: " + item);

It shows alert messages like this:

[image: ID]

[image: Date]

[image: Status]

I simply want to show the results in the html table.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item your JSON is returning is not a collection, but a single object. So your "each" function is iterating over the properties of the object, rather than through objects in a collection. Here's a simplified version of your question ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this is probably what you should have submitted as the code for your question):

```js
var data = JSON.parse('{"ID":1,"Date":"2015-10-26T00:00:00","Status":"Initiated","Action":{"VerificationActionTypeID":0,"VerificationActionType":null,"VerificationActionTakenID":0,"VerificationActionTaken":null,"VerficationActionCreateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","EmailAddress":null,"Notes":null},"Actions":[{"VerificationActionTypeID":0,"VerificationActionType":"Perform Rinse Flowcell","VerificationActionTakenID":0,"VerificationActionTaken":"Skip","VerficationActionCreateDate":"2015-10-26T10:04:05.093","EmailAddress":null,"Notes":null}]}');

$.each(data, function(key, item) {
  alert("action: " + item);
  $('#actions tbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.ID + '</td><td>' + item.Status + '</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="actions">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You will need to decide what object you want to loop over (of if a loop is even necessary). You have a collection of actions, and your HTML table is named actions. Perhaps you want to loop over the actions returned in the response, and add those to the table?

```js
var data = JSON.parse('{"ID":1,"Date":"2015-10-26T00:00:00","Status":"Initiated","Action":{"VerificationActionTypeID":0,"VerificationActionType":null,"VerificationActionTakenID":0,"VerificationActionTaken":null,"VerficationActionCreateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","EmailAddress":null,"Notes":null},"Actions":[{"VerificationActionTypeID":0,"VerificationActionType":"Perform Rinse Flowcell","VerificationActionTakenID":0,"VerificationActionTaken":"Skip","VerficationActionCreateDate":"2015-10-26T10:04:05.093","EmailAddress":null,"Notes":null}]}');
  
$.each(data.Actions, function (key, item) {
     alert("action id: " + item.VerificationActionTypeID);
     $('#actions tbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.VerificationActionTypeID + '</td><td>'+item.VerficationActionCreateDate+'</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="actions">
    <thead>
        <th>Action Type Id</th><th>VerficationActionCreateDate</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```